# Where are the MethodBuilder, ModuleBuilder and AssemblyBuilder in dotnet core?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I am migrating a .Net Framework library to .Net standard and the compiler cannot find the core builders from `System.Reflection.Emit`.

If I am in the right place then the API documentation states that these builders (`MethodBuilder`, `ModuleBuilder` and `AssemblyBuilder`) are part of [`System.Reflection.Emit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.reflection.emit).

This is the `project.json` for my library:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need any additional reference?

Answer (score 11):

You can find them in `"System.Reflection.Emit": "4.3.0"` nugget package for the netstandard1.6 framework.

Comment: This package is unlisted. Not sure why, and what we're supposed to use instead...

Answer (score 2):

The "animalito maquina" answer also worked for me but I have investigated the problem a little bit using netstandard2.0. It might not be relevant to this question but I wanted to share this with you since it still might help others :).

I generated two projects(dotnet new):

- "classlib" which uses netstandard2.0 on default
- ...and "console" which uses the netcoreapp2.0

I  added references to AssemblyBuilder class in both projects. The AssemblyBuilder was missing in "classlib" project that has been using netstandard2.0 but was available in "console" project - netcoreapp2.0.

The "problem" is caused by the fact that [.NET Core Libraries are actually always a superset of the APIs defined in the corresponding version of the .NET Standard. There are always types and members available in the .NET Core Libraries, which are not (yet?) part of the .NET Standard.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868713/7944632)

These links might be helpful:

- https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/docs/comparisons
- [Advantages of netcoreapp2.0 vs netstandard2.0 for a library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867239/advantages-of-netcoreapp2-0-vs-netstandard2-0-for-a-library-project)
- https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/comparisons/netstandard2.0_vs_netcoreapp2.0/README.md
- https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7335