# Advantages of netcoreapp2.0 vs netstandard2.0 for a library project

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a preexisting dotnet 4.6.2 solution that comprises of two outer projects (to be ported at the same time) and a shared `core` library.

I need to choose the core assembly's `TargetFramework`, which could either be `netcoreapp2.0` or `netstandard2.0`.

Since it won't be executable, or referenced by any external project, are there any advantages one way or the other?

Comment: You get to program the library with your hands tied behind your back.  Ensuring that you cannot write any code that won't run on another platform.  Whether that is an advantage or a liability is something you'll inevitably find out by yourself.

Comment: I happen to be writing a backend accounting system for a bank - in my specific use case, I'd be very surprised if it ends up in a xamarin or UWP app! So long as it works on windows and linux containers, I'll be happy :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They differ in nature:

- The [.NET Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard) is a set of APIs (standard)
- The [.NET Core Libraries](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) are a set of libraries (implementation)

Each version of the .NET Core Librairies implements (at least) a given version of the .NET Standard, and a complete table can be found in the [.NET Standard documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md). Right now, the latest versions are in sync (2.0 - 2.0), but this hasn't been and won't always be true.

The .NET Core Libraries are actually always a superset of the APIs defined in the corresponding version of the .NET Standard. There are always types and members available in the .NET Core Libraries, which are not (yet?) part of the .NET Standard. Microsoft publishes [namespace-by-namespace comparisons of the available APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/docs/comparisons).

Your library might use an API that has not yet been standardized in the .NET Standard (or might never be), but is already available in .NET Core Libraries. As an example, you might use types from the System.Drawing namespace, that will soon be available in the .NET Core Libraries, but won't be part of the .NET Standard 2.0.

So, by choosing netcoreapp2.0 over netstandard2.0, you gain access to a larger API, at the expense of compatibility.

On a general note, **you should always try to target the most portable framework (here, netstandard)**.

If it is not an option for you, the next best thing would be to cross-target multiple frameworks from a single library, as explained here: [How do you multi-target a .NET Core class library with csproj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747977/how-do-you-multi-target-a-net-core-class-library-with-csproj). Many .NET Core APIs missing from the .NET Standard are also present in the (full) .NET Framework.

Comment: With necessary respect, that is all accurate but terrible advice. Libraries should always try to target `netstandard`. `netcoreapp` libraries will not restore on Xamarin or .NET Framework.

Comment: I'll try to reformulate the answer to take your remark into account.

Comment: I hope this new version addresses some of your concerns, @Thomas.

Comment: Not really sorry. `netcoreapp` in a library allows the library only be used on the x-plat .NET Core but not Xamarin, Unity3D, Mono or the normal .NET Framework. That is maybe okay for the questioner but not in general. The most portable is `netstandard1.0` with the smallest API set.

Comment: Oh, that one was a typo. Fixed. Thank you for your vigilance.

Answer (score 5):

NetStandard is new recommended library format that enables sharing between different frameworks(NetFramwwork, NetCore, Xamarin) so that would be the answer.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

Comment: I am going with netcoreapp2.0 for two reasons: It's a super-set of netstandard, which could potentially (although probably not) save us from some compatibility issues and we just don't need the portability aspect of netstandard - the library will be shared by a couple of netcore2.0 apps, nothing else.

Comment: In that case it's fine, especially for private libraries.

Comment: @JonBates Forward looking you should try to target the lowest `netstandard`. Microsoft considers the `netstandard` as the formalization of BCL. Just try it.