# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet v2.0.1

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Currently Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet V2.0.1 is showing  a dependency of .NetCoreApp **Version = 2.0**

Any reason why that isnt version >=2.0 ?
Any idea when support for the more recent versions of 
 [.NetCore SDK](http://Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet)  will be available

**EDIT:**  Added screenshot
[image: Nuget in VS 2017]
See dependency listed as .NetCoreApp = v2.0 and not .NetStandard = V2.0  or >= CoreApp V2.0 for similar packages.

**edit2:**
I ran the following new Project tests:
i still think there is an issue here.
I have .netcore sdk 2.1.4 installed
I started with brand new solution in VS2017 15.5.5

I create a new core project 
   netcoreapp2.0 
and a new standard project
 netstandard2.0

These packages

o Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools v2.0.1
 o Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.design v2.0.1
 o Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v2.0.1
 o Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

can all be successfully installed in both projects 
 netstandard2.0
and
   netcoreapp2.0

However: 
**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet v2.0.1** 
   can not be installed in netstandard2.0 project, which I can live with and the error makes some sense.

> Restoring packages for C:_Dev\PJSTest\PJSStd\PJSStd.csproj... Package
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.1 is not compatible
>   with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.1 supports:
>   netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0) Package restore failed.
>   Rolling back package changes for 'PJSStd'. Time Elapsed:
>   00:00:00.1634807
>   ========== Finished ==========

BUT

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet v2.0.1

can not be even be  installed in a netcoreapp2.0   project

> Restoring packages for C:_Dev\EFTEST\EFCore\EFCore.csproj... Detected
>   package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.3 to 2.0.0.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version.   EFCore -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.1
>   -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.3)   EFCore -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0) Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'EFCore'. Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.1413809
>   ========== Finished ==========

**I think there is an issue with versioning on the CoreApp dependency.**

Comment: Where are you seeing that dependency version? Looks like it [needs >= 2.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet/2.0.1) to me

Comment: If you manually add the following to your new test csproj file (in an `<ItemGroup>`), do you get the same error? `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to be corrected, but my understanding is that **.NetCoreApp** (v2) is the **platform**, whereas **.NetCore.App** (v2.0.5, currently) is the set of API's that *target* that platform.

So the fact that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet V2.0.1 only points to .NetCoreApp,Version = 2.0 means it can only support the apis from that platform... which says nothing about what platforms those dependencies support. e.g. you if you take a further and look inside at the Microsoft.NetCore.App dependencies, you will see listings under .NetCoreApp,Version = 1.0 up to 2.0.

**EDIT:** My understanding of various .NET core versioning landscape goes as follows:

1. The `.NET Core SDK` version is 2.1.5. This allows the building of .NET standard and .NET core apps.
2. The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` version is 2.0.1. This references .netcoreapp2.0
3. .netcoreapp2.0 is the platform that implements `Microsoft.NetCore.App`, which is currently version 2.0.5 of the runtime.

The key part of netcoreapp2.0 is its dependence on .NETStandard.Library (netstandard2.0) but netstandard2.0 does not depend on netcoreapp2.0. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868713/3419825) explains it better than I can. So the EntityFramework cli tools won't work on a library that uses .netstandard2.0 because it targets .netcoreapp2.0. Incidentally, EFCore does work - because it targets .netstandard - just the tools won't.

In summary, the SDK that you have, at version 2.1.4, already contains the necessary .NET Core platforms and runtimes. So no downgrade to the original version 2 is required. <strike>What needs to happen is that the csproj has to be updated to target the .NET Core runtime instead in order to use the tools: `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`.</strike>

**EDIT2:** Here's a sample of a csproj file that targets .netstandard (so that UWP can reference it), and is able to use the EFCore tools.DotNet:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is a package reference that targets .NET Standard. the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` is a tools reference and is treated differently to package references. So the versioning and targets are also a little different.

Comment: So im forced to install an older .netcore version? Im using 2.1.4 currently. If so then this is the answer.  The tooling is locked to a very specific Core version and not >= core version.

Comment: @philsoady Oh I think I now see what the issue is. I checked the EF tools source code and it targets netcoreapp2.0, not netstandard2.0. Long story short, the tools you have are correct - no need to downgrade - you will need to update your target framework to `netcoreapp2.0`. I'll update my answer now with further details...

Comment: Could well be the right answer, but when I change the target framework i get a solution error ´EFTEST.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'UAP,Version=v10.0.16299'.´

Comment: @philsoady The UWP part reveals a wrong assumption that I made. Currently you can't install tools via NuGet, so you need to make manual edits, like the sample csproj file. But I think that will [change soon-ish](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4190).

Comment: Yes! I'm using EF Core 2.1.3 and Visual Studio Code. I Have put the property privateAssets="all" on hand. Nuget Package Doesn't that!